# How do i print one value of 'end' after detecting one '0' and revert back into detecting '1's

Tags: python, loops

my code currently

[image]

so basically this is my code now and i only want one 'end' to be printed when it detects a value 0 in my excel sheet. The main output i want is when the value is '1', like in this image (main output) but without so many 'end's.

```
#Duration loop
for i in range(len(dfDur01Mar22)):
    #only display bus 'SG3079S'
    if dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,1] == 'SG3079S':
        #print 'end' when first '0' appears
        if dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,2] == 0:
           print('end')
        #if charging type is 1
        elif dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,2] == 1: print(dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,0],dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,1],dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,2])
```

main output
[image]

Comment: Use a flag, like `i_found_a_1 = False`.  Set it true when you find one.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please copy and paste your code as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe @TimRoberts in the comments gave the correct answer, I will just expand upon it by showing you how to use it.

I slightly modified your code as I did not have your file, but the concept is all that's important. You use a simple bool variable as a sentinel and check if it is set, if it isn't then run the rest of the check for the end value. This is probably the best way to solve this type of problem from the information you have provided. Code:

```
import random


dfDur01Mar22 = []
for i in range(0,20):
    chargingType = random.choice([0, 1, 1])
    dfDur01Mar22.append(['', 'SG3079S', chargingType])





foundEnd = False

#Duration loop
for i in range(len(dfDur01Mar22)):
    #only display bus 'SG3079S'
    if dfDur01Mar22[i][1] == 'SG3079S':
        #print 'end' when first '0' appears
        if not foundEnd and dfDur01Mar22[i][2] == 0:
            print('end')
            foundEnd = True
        #if charging type is 1
        elif dfDur01Mar22[i][2] == 1:
            print(dfDur01Mar22[i][0],dfDur01Mar22[i][1],dfDur01Mar22[i][2])
```

Example of output:

```
With check  :   Without check

SG3079S 1       SG3079S 1
SG3079S 1       SG3079S 1
SG3079S 1       SG3079S 1
SG3079S 1       end
end             end
SG3079S 1       SG3079S 1
SG3079S 1       end
SG3079S 1       SG3079S 1
SG3079S 1       end
SG3079S 1       SG3079S 1
SG3079S 1       SG3079S 1
SG3079S 1       end
                end
                SG3079S 1
                SG3079S 1
                SG3079S 1
                SG3079S 1
                SG3079S 1
                SG3079S 1
                SG3079S 1
```

Comment: @heyshh glad i could help(though the real hero is TimRoberts )! Dont forget to mark this answer as the solution if it fixed your problem, it helps others with the same problem find the solution too :)